# Windows server file permissions - prompt raised

Tags: security, file-permissions, windows-server-2012, windows-server

Local network with domain D, user U is member of group G in D.

Windows Server 2012 R2 machine M, also in D.

File F on local disk on M. Entire disk has All permissions given to G.

When U is connected to M with Remote desktop, he can rename F, but he gets prompt "File Acesss Denied", "You'll need to provide administrator permission to rename this file". He can click Continue and cmd is executed.

If I give all permissions to U, he can rename F without prompt raised.

Why this difference exists between U and G? How to give same rights to G?

Answer (score 0):

All working as expected after M was restarted.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the answer to your problem. After the reboot, the user is actually seen as member of the group, not while you just added it. When you make a user member of a group, those rights are fetched only during login time. If you have a user who is member of a group, and you make that group member of another group, no reboot is necessary.